# In tmux on remote machine, each new line in terminal is indented to the end of the previously displayed line

Tags: ssh, terminal, tmux, openconnect

### Update: Solved thanks to comment by @NotTheDr01ds

#### Original question

(Details of the machines I'm using at end)

I connect to a my Uni's VPN using:

`sudo /sbin/modprobe tun && sudo openconnect gucsasa1.cent.gla.ac.uk`

I get this output:

```
POST https://gucsasa1.cent.gla.ac.uk/
Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CSTP connected. DPD 30, Keepalive 20
Connected as 172.20.183.165, using SSL, with DTLS in progress
Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS1.2)-(ECDHE-RSA)-(AES-256-GCM).
Unknown DTLS packet type 13, len 16
```

Then I run the following command to connect via ssh:

```
ssh -X mymachine
```

Once connected, my .bashrc on the server tries to automatically launches tmux
(version 2.6):

```
# Launch tmux
if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then
    [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && tmux new-session -A -s main
fi
```

But it instantly crashes leaving my terminal display looking like this (here I
typed `ls` to show the problem, but it happens with all stdout):

[image: After typing 'clear' and then typing 'ls']

I also can't see anything I'm typing into the terminal - i.e. it doesn't update
the display until I hit enter on the command (having typed it 'blind').

When using the `-X` and `-Y` flags with ssh, I have no problems with GUI
programs. This is specific to stdout rendering in the terminal in tmux.

After googling, I found that typing `reset` brought back a 'normal' experience,
but also killed the tmux server. Here is the result of typing `ls`:

[image: After typing 'reset' and then typing 'ls']

As soon as I try to launch tmux, it crashes again and I'm back to the original
problem.

I don't have this problem when I connect to other servers (running Debian 10,
and Ubuntu 20.04, bash and tmux 2.8) using the same client machine and same
terminal.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can troubleshoot this issue? I've been
googling all day without success.

##### Client machine

- OS: lubuntu 20.04
- terminal: st
- shell: bash
- In tmux session: `echo $TERM`: st-256color
- Outside tmux session: `echo $TERM`: screen-256color

##### Server machine

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- terminal: gnome-terminal
- shell: bash
- Outside tmux session: `echo $TERM`: st-256color

Comment: Which shell is running in `tmux` on the remote host? What is the value of the `TERM` variable in that shell?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show an example of the actual ssh command that you're running, including any relevant entries from your ssh config?

Comment: @fra-san Thanks for you comment - I updated the question. Please let me know if you need any other information!

Comment: @Kenster I updated the question to include the ssh command. I don't find any config file in the ~/.ssh directory on either my client or server. So I guess I don't have one (unless I'm missing something). Thanks for you help so far!

Comment: @mattb I just tried as close a test as I could to replicate your problem.  I'm not over a tunnel, but I went from Ubuntu 20.04 with st to one of my Ubuntu 18.04 hosts via SSH.  I couldn't reproduce your problem.  Can you try two things?  First, does the problem happen with another terminal?  Second, try adding `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` to your `~/.tmux.conf` and restarting `tmux`.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thank you! Your comment led me to the problem! I tried with
gnome-terminal on the client (instead of st) and it worked. `echo $TERM` on the
gnome-terminal gave `xterm-256color`. I did have `set -g default-terminal
"screen-256color"` in my `~/.tmux.conf`, on both machines, but I wasn't running
tmux on the client and so `echo $TERM` was `st-256color`. In  the end, staying
with an st terminal, and doing `export TERM=xterm-256color` before connecting
through ssh did the trick. Maybe you'd like to create and answer and receive the upvotes/accepts. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this myself using a similar configuration, but it sounds like (and confirmed from the comments) that there may be a mismatch with the termcap and `$TERM` (`st-256color`) on the host.

There are a few things I'd try:

- First, see if the same issue happens with a different terminal.  In this case, `gnome-terminal` worked correctly.
- Experiment with different `TERM` setting, such as `tmux-256color`, `screen-256color`, or `xterm-256color`.
- *(What worked in this case)* `export TERM=xterm-256color` on the client before connecting to the host.  `TERM=xterm256color ssh -X mymachine` should also work.